# Trigger to update field value in one table from another that get insertion

Tags: sql

I have an SQL database table named `ItemMenu` with 5 fields named: `PLU` (primary key), `description`, `size`, `price`, `department`. This table is populated with active records.

Now, I created another table with only 2 fields, one of which is called `PLU` and the other is `Price`. This new table is named `Price_import` and gets its records from an MS Access linked table whenever I want to send records to SQL table `ItemMenu`.

I am trying to create a trigger that would update only the price of a certain `PLU` in the `ItemMenu` every time I send that change to the `Price_import` table in SQL. Once the the price is updated in the `ItemMenu` table I would like to have records cleared from the `Price_import` table automatically if possible, but it is not that important. I am just an enthusiast who wants to know how SQL works, therefore; would appreciate some help with this.

Comment: please update your questions and give us your tables's description with I can do a trigger to you

Comment: Thanks mugiwaradz,The table to have the trigger is Named Price_inport. It has 2 fields: PLU which is the primary key and Price. What I am trying to do is to create a trigger; that when new PLU and Price records are added to the Price_Import table, will update the price based on the primary key (PLU) in another table named MenuItem within the same database. Example: if I add a record with PL=012456 and a Price of 1.25 to the Import_Price table, I want to see price updated in my main table MenuItem and If possible have the values in the Price_Import table cleared after this update process

Comment: Please update the question with (a) the information from your comment, (b) with the specific DBMS you are using (I suspect MS SQL Server, but state it anyway), and (c) paragraph breaks (blank lines) so that the question isn't a solid wall of text.

Comment: Please update the question with (a) the information from your comment, (b) with the specific DBMS you are using (I suspect MS SQL Server, but state it anyway), and (c) paragraph breaks (blank lines) so that the question isn't a solid wall of text. I've made some changes for you, but I've not merged your comment into the question.  Please note that consistency in the use names is important too.  The price import table was spelled in a variety of ways.

Answer (score 0):

MyDatabase        set ANSI_NULLS ON
        set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
        GO
--This trigger is attached to the Price_Import Table so when this table gets new price values the trigger will update the price of such items in the Mydatabase MenuItem Table which is the main item table in Mydatabase

```
     ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgafterinsertinto_Price_Import_Table] ON [dbo].[Price_Import]
AFTER INSERT
    AS 
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

-- update your table, using a set-based approach
-- from the "Inserted" pseudo table which CAN and        -- WILL
-- contain multiple rows!

```
     UPDATE [dbo].[MenuItem] 
SET [Price] = i.[Price] ,[Cost] = i.[Cost]
    FROM Inserted i
   WHERE MenuItem.PLU = i.PLU
   DELETE FROM dbo.Price_Import
   END
```